# When should I use a FutureBuilder?

Tags: dart, flutter, future, builder

I was wondering when I should use the future builder. For example, if I want to make an http request and show the results in a list view, as soon as you open the view, should I have to use the future builder or just build a `ListViewBuilder` like:

```
new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _features.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
...stuff here...
}
```

Moreover, if I don't want to build a list view but some more complex stuff like circular charts, should I have to use the future builder?

Hope it's clear enough!

Comment: You dont have to, you could also define a List with widgets, and update it with setState. The listview will update when you set the state. `doStuff()async{ var stuff = await getStuff(); setState((){list = stuff;});}` if you use a StatefulWidget ofcourse.

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 196, accepted):

`FutureBuilder` removes boilerplate code.

Let's say you want to fetch some data from the backend on page launch and show a loader until data comes.

**Tasks for ListBuilder:**

- Have two state variables, `dataFromBackend` and `isLoadingFlag`
- On launch, set `isLoadingFlag = true`, and based on this, show `loader`.
- Once data arrives, set data with what you get from backend and set `isLoadingFlag = false` (inside `setState` obviously)
- We need to have a `if-else` in widget creation. If `isLoadingFlag` is `true`, show the `loader` else show the `data`. On failure, show error message.

**Tasks for FutureBuilder:**

- Give the async task in `future` of Future Builder
- Based on `connectionState`, show message (`loading`, `active(streams)`, `done`)
- Based on `data(snapshot.hasError)`, show view

**Pros of FutureBuilder**

- Does not use the two state variables and `setState`
- Reactive programming (`FutureBuilder` will take care of updating the view on data arrival)

**Example:**

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _fetchNetworkCall, // async work
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
       switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
         case ConnectionState.waiting: return Text('Loading....');
         default:
           if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
           else
          return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
        }
      },
    )
```

**Performance impact:**

I just looked into the `FutureBuilder` code to understand the **performance** impact of using this.

- FutureBuilder is just a `StatefulWidget` whose `state` variable is `_snapshot`
- Initial state is `_snapshot = AsyncSnapshot<T>.withData(ConnectionState.none, widget.initialData);`
- It is subscribing to `future` which we send via the constructor and update the `state` based on that.

**Example:**

```
widget.future.then<void>((T data) {
    if (_activeCallbackIdentity == callbackIdentity) {
      setState(() {
        _snapshot = AsyncSnapshot<T>.withData(ConnectionState.done, data);
      });
    }
}, onError: (Object error) {
  if (_activeCallbackIdentity == callbackIdentity) {
    setState(() {
      _snapshot = AsyncSnapshot<T>.withError(ConnectionState.done, error);
    });
  }
});
```

So the `FutureBuilder` is a **wrapper/boilerplate** of what we do typically, hence there **should not be any performance impact**.

Comment: So I don't need it, but this decision would be a bad one since it helps me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Very good question. After your question, I looked into the flutter code. @SamarthAgarwal I update the answer related to performance. Thanks

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian thanks for the quick update. Also, are you aware of any side effects of using `setState()` inside the future that we use with `FutureBuilder`. I tried that and turns out that the future is executed recursively. Can you suspect something?

Comment: U mean `setState` inside `future` method?. Can you provide some simple code snippet

Comment: What if I want to fetch data on press of a button and show circular progress indicator till that is done? Can `FutureBuilder` be used now? If yes, How?

Comment: @Keerti purswani make a future method where you are fetching data from the backend and then call that method in the future builder. If you want more information [click here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: why not check against `ConnectionState.done` rather than against `ConnectionState.waiting` ?

Comment: had a question about future builder, declared a variable inside build method, now i need to use it outside of the build method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70980002/flutter-use-variable-created-inside-future-builder-outside-of-the-build-method

Answer (score 27):

**FutureBuilder Example**

- When you want to  rander widget after async call then use  **`FutureBuilder()`**

  ```
  class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: downloadData(), // function where you call your api
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {  // AsyncSnapshot<Your object type>
        if( snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return  Center(child: Text('Please wait its loading...'));
        }else{
            if (snapshot.hasError)
              return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
            else
              return Center(child: new Text('${snapshot.data}'));  // snapshot.data  :- get your object which is pass from your downloadData() function
        }
      },
    );
  }
  Future<String> downloadData()async{
    //   var response =  await http.get('https://getProjectList');    
    return Future.value("Data download successfully"); // return your response
  }
  }
  ```

In future builder, it calls the future function to wait for the result, and as soon as it produces the result it calls the builder function where we build the widget.

AsyncSnapshot has 3 state:

1. **connectionState.none** = In this state future is null
2. **connectionState.waiting** = [future] is not null, but has not yet completed
3. **connectionState.done** = [future] is not null, and has completed. If the future completed successfully, the [AsyncSnapshot.data] will be set to the value to which the future completed. If it completed with an error, [AsyncSnapshot.hasError] will be true

Comment: It should be noted that the downloadData() function will be executed for every time through the build(...) function.  Best practice is to call downloadData() and save the returned Future to a variable in your State object, and reference that variable in the future: parameter

Answer (score 19):

FutureBuilder is a Widget that will help you to execute some asynchronous function and based on that function’s result your UI will update.

I listed some use cases, why you will use FutureBuilder?

1. If you want to render widget after async task then use it.
2. We can handle loading process by simply using `ConnectionState.waiting`
3. Don't need any custom error controller. Can handle error simply `dataSnapshot.error != null`
4. As we can handle async task within the builder we do not need any `setState(() { _isLoading = false; });`

When we use the FutureBuilder widget we need to check for future state i.e future is resolved or not and so on. There are various State as follows:

1. `ConnectionState.none:`  It means that the future is null and initialData is used as defaultValue.
2. `ConnectionState.active:` It means the future is not null but it is not resolved yet.
3. `ConnectionState.waiting:` It means the future is being resolved, and we will get the result soon enough.
4. `ConnectionState.done:` It means that the future has been resolved.

A simple implementation

Here OrdersProvider is a provider class and fetchAndSetOrders() is the method of that provider class.

```
body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<OrdersProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAndSetOrders(),
        builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            if (dataSnapshot.error != null) {
              return Center(
                child: Text('An error occured'),
              );
            } else {
              return Consumer<OrdersProvider>(
                builder: (context, orderData, child) => ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: orderData.orders.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) => OrderItem(orderData.orders[i]),
                ),
              );
            }
          }
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

FutureBuilder is a widget in Flutter that is used to perform asynchronous operations and rebuild the UI when the operation is complete. It's particularly useful when you need to fetch data from a remote server or perform any other asynchronous task.

You should use FutureBuilder when:

Fetching Data from a Future:
If you have a function that returns a Future, such as making a network request or reading from a database, you can use FutureBuilder to handle the asynchronous nature of these operations.

Displaying Loading or Error States:
FutureBuilder makes it easy to display loading indicators or error messages while the asynchronous operation is in progress or encounters an error. This helps provide a better user experience.

Updating UI After Async Operation:
When the asynchronous operation is complete, and you want to update the UI with the result, FutureBuilder allows you to define how the UI should look based on the success or failure of the future.

See more examples [Futurebuilder](https://www.fluttertpoint.in/futurebuilder-flutter)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).