# Display reference of a document snapshot in a streambuilder listview

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[Here's my database (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juoKH.png)

So I can display all books to the user in a pretty standard way using listview:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
          default:
            return new ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(document['text']),
                  subtitle: // I want to display the author's name
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
```

But the problem is, `document['author']` is a `DocumentReference`, which I can get by `DocumentSnapshot ds = await documentSnapshot['author'].get()`. But the problem is, this is a future which I cannot use inside the ListView. What is the best way to go about this? Use a Futurebuilder for each document snapshot? I also have multiple document references for each book in my actual project

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `FutureBuilder` instead of a `StreamBuilder`. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983699/3266152) it also removes some builder plate code. Let me know how this unfolds. You can always return a `ListView.builder` if your snapshot does not contain any errors. That's my approach.