# firestore flutter no results

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

```
Future<List> getHistory() async {
List images;
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =
    (await Firestore.instance.collection("History").getDocuments()).documents;
images = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['images']).toList();
return images;
}
```

Hi all, what am I doing wrong here, it never returns images. I am sure that I am not doing this the correct way so any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomePage> {
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();    
    getHistory();

  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the images but not doing anything with the return value, Try this:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomePage> {
    List images;

    Future<List> getHistory() async {
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents =  (await 
    Firestore.instance.collection("History").getDocuments()).documents;
    images = documents.map((documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot['images']).toList();
   }

   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();    
    getHistory();

  }
```

And in the widget tree use a future builder that awaits getHistory()'s results

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry but am new to Flutter and Im not sure how to implement "And in the widget tree use a future builder that awaits getHistory()'s results" I will hit google for material.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983011/flutter-future-builder-when-should-i-use-it