# How to return a string from a Future<String> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, translation

This is the code I have been trying. I want to return a `String` using `extractInfo()` method.

How can we return a `String` because the parameter is not accepting any other argument than the `String`

```
      Future<String> info(String x) a sync{
        final translator = Google Translator();
        return await translator.translate(x, to: 'en');
      }
      String y;
      String extract Info(){
        String x = "Title :${widget.userPosts[widget.index].title}\n"
            "User Id :${widget.userPosts[widget.index].userId}\n"
            "Id :${widget.userPosts[widget.index].id}\n"
            "Completed :${widget.userPosts[widget.index].completed}\n";
    
        info(x).then((value) => y = value);
        print(y);
        return x;
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("More"),
          ),
          body: StoryView(
            storyItems: [
              StoryItem.text(
                title: extractInfo(),
                backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
              )
            ],
            onStoryShow: (s) {
              print("Showing a story");
            },
            onComplete: () {
              print("Completed a cycle");
            },
            progressPosition: ProgressPosition.top,
            repeat: false,
            controller: story Controller,
          ),`
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You will need to use `async`/`await` like you did in the first method. Since your control does not accept a `Future<String>` you will need to wrap it in a `FutureBuilder`. You can see how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983011/flutter-future-builder-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: If I will use future builder I cannot use story items plz help me out here

Comment: Why not? I don't know how to help you, without a better problem description.

Comment: We would like to show our data as in instagram story. We are translating the data recieved frm the api. Everything is working but this translated data we are not able to show

Comment: So, make one function to translate the data, since that will return a `Future<YourData>`, you will need a `FutureBuilder` to properly build your UI.