# snapshot.data is Null. I'm using a for loop to iterate over JSON data and create a list of object instances

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm retrieving json data from json-generator.com and parsing it to create a list of companies in the below code. When i print JsonData variable i can see the data but snapshot.data is null. here's my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './Object.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'UI_Styles/Company_Card_Style.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Companies extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CompaniesState createState() => _CompaniesState();
}

class _CompaniesState extends State<Companies> {
  Future<List<Company>> _getCompanies() async {
    var data = await http.get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUYmnsimgi?indent=2");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<Company> companies = [];
    for (var c in jsonData) {
      Company company = Company(
          c["name"],
          c["opportunites"],
          c["address"],
          c["city"],
          c["state"],
          c["country"],
          c["zipcode"],
          c["phone"],
          c["timezone"],
          c["pipelineRevenue"],
          c["revenueAchieved"],
          c["tags"]);
      companies.add(company);
    }
    return companies;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getCompanies(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return CompanyCardStyle(company: snapshot.data[index]);
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Here is my company object

```
class Company {
  String name;
  String address;
  int opportunities;
  int pipelineRevenue;
  int revenueAchieved;
  String city;
  String state;
  String country;
  int zipcode;
  double phone;
  String timezone;
  String tags;

  Company(
      this.name,
      this.address,
      this.opportunities,
      this.pipelineRevenue,
      this.revenueAchieved,
      this.city,
      this.state,
      this.country,
      this.zipcode,
      this.phone,
      this.timezone,
      this.tags);
}
```

I think there is some issue with the for loop but i cant figure out what's wrong I'm new to parsing data like that.

Comment: You might be interested in giving a look to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983011/when-should-i-use-a-futurebuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing some things wrong:

1. Some fields coming from the endpoint were given the wrong `data type` (the phone number required a `String` but you used a `double`. The `tags` also returns a `List` but you used a `String`.
2. You swapped most of the constructor fields with one another when you were converting the `jsonData` to a `Company` object.

Solution:

1. Make a factory constructor for your `Company` class that makes json deserialization easier. You can check the official documentation for an example.
2. Use correct data types for each of your fields.

**Note: I made the `tag` field a `String` and only access the first element in the list coming from the api.**

*COMPANY CLASS*

```
class Company {
  String name;
  String address;
  int opportunities;
  int pipelineRevenue;
  int revenueAchieved;
  String city;
  String state;
  String country;
  int zipcode;
  String phone;
  String timezone;
  String tags;

  Company(
      this.name,
      this.address,
      this.opportunities,
      this.pipelineRevenue,
      this.revenueAchieved,
      this.city,
      this.state,
      this.country,
      this.zipcode,
      this.phone,
      this.timezone,
      this.tags);

  // make a constructor for converting json to a company object
  factory Company.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Company(
      json["name"],
      json["address"],
      json["opportunities"],
      json["pipelineRevenue"],
      json["revenueAchieved"],
      json["city"],
      json["state"],
      json["country"],
      json["zipcode"],
      json["phone"],
      json["timezone"],
      json["tags"][0],
    );
  }
}
```

- COMPANIES WIDGET*

```
class Companies extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CompaniesState createState() => _CompaniesState();
}

class _CompaniesState extends State<Companies> {
  Future<List<Company>> _getCompanies() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bUYmnsimgi?indent=2");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body) as List;
    List<Company> companies = [];
    // convert the json to a list of companies
    companies = jsonData
        .map((company) => Company.fromJson(company))
        .toList(); // new line
    print(companies.length);
    return companies;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _getCompanies(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        // use your company card here
                        return Text(
                            'Company $index name: ${snapshot.data[index].name}');
                      });
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks for the effort, really appreciate it. will implement the factory function. however why did you put [0] beside tags in factory function

Comment: Because `tag` returns a `List` so I selected the first element of the list since I didn't have an idea of what your `CompanyCardStyle` looked like.

Comment: ok! to display in the demo app you made. Got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because the FutureBuilder returns an Error event. You can check what error it is by accessing `snapshot.error` (or `snapshot.hasError` to check if there are any error).

When I tried your code, the error said `Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'`. Looks like it's problem when you are instantiating `Company` object. Some of properties (like `opportunities`) need `int`, but you give it in `String` because the value in the decoded json is String. You need to parse it to `int` first.

Comment: Thanks, how do i parse it to int first in for loop

Comment: Ah looks like I missed the order you instantiate. Looks like answer from Unbreachable is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the website and noticed that you had some of the types incorrect. For example *tags* is a *list*, but you put it as a *String*. The same thing with the *phone number*, it is supposed to be a String, not a double. And since you are not using *named parameters*, you will need to place your properties from the constructor in the *same* order whenever you create an instance of that class.

```
class Company {
  String name;
  String address;
  int opportunities;
  int pipelineRevenue;
  int revenueAchieved;
  String city;
  String state;
  String country;
  int zipcode;
  String phone;
  String timezone;
  List tags;

  Company(
    this.name,
    this.opportunities,
    this.address,
    this.city,
    this.state,
    this.country,
    this.zipcode,
    this.phone,
    this.timezone,
    this.pipelineRevenue,
    this.revenueAchieved,
    this.tags);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, realized the named parameter part but not the initialization.