# How to call method only after async method finishes

Tags: flutter, asynchronous

**Background**
I have a class *PriceScreen* that contains an asynchronous method *getData()*. This *PriceScreen* class makes a call to class *Graph* using data from *graphValues* returned from *getData()*.

**Problem**
The call to *Graph* `Graph(closingTimesAndPrices: graphValues)`

is running before *getData* is completed, resulting in the passed *graphValues* becoming Null in the call above. How can I change my code so that the call to *Graph* waits to be called until *getData*  is finished processing?

Note: I have added "<<<----------" to parts of the code that I believe are important to answering my question.

```
class PriceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PriceScreenState createState() => PriceScreenState();
}

class PriceScreenState extends State < PriceScreen > {
  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';
  String selectedGraphType = "1M";
  Map < String,
  String > coinValues = {};
  Map < String,
  double > graphValues = {};

  bool isWaiting = false;

  void getData() async {<<< -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -
    isWaiting = true;
    try {
      Map coinData = await CoinData().getCoinData(selectedCurrency);
      Map graphData = await GraphData().getGraphData( <<< -- -- -- -- -
        selectedCurrency: selectedCurrency,
        selectedGraphType: selectedGraphType);
      isWaiting = false;
      setState(() {
        coinValues = coinData;
        graphValues = graphData; <<< -- -- -- -- -- -
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Crypto Watcher'),
      ),
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: < Widget > [
            Graph(closingTimesAndPrices: graphValues), <<< -- -- --
          ]),
        inAsyncCall: isWaiting,
        progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to those who have responded to my question and for recommending the use of StreamBuilder. I used StreamBuilder to overcome the issue from my Original Post.

I needed to add three parts to my code:

```
 1) Future futureData;

 2) futureData = getData();

 3) FutureBuilder(
                future: futureData,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (graphValues.isEmpty) {
                    return new Container();
                  } else
                  return Graph(closingTimesAndPrices: graphValues);
                })
```

I used *futureData* for the value of `future:` in the FutureBuilder to signal that I am waiting on *futureData* (*getData();*) to fully complete before I return anything. In my Original Post, I mentioned that *graphValues* were returning null before *getData()* was finished processing. To remedy this, I check if *graphValues* is empty with

```
                      if (graphValues.isEmpty) {
                        return new Container();
                      } else
                      return Graph(closingTimesAndPrices: graphValues);
```

If *graphValues* is empty, I return *new Container();* which doesn't show anything to the user. When *graphValues* is not empty, I return the call to Graph with `Graph(closingTimesAndPrices: graphValues);`. Some may recommend that I include a *CircularProgressIndicator* instead of `new Container();` when *graphValues* is empty, but I already have a *CircularProgressIndicator* as indicated by `body: ModalProgressHUD(` and

```
inAsyncCall: isWaiting,
        progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
```

Here are some resources that helped me learn StreamBuilder and helped me solve the problem:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYN46233cws

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450354/3932449

The additions to my code are denoted with three asterisks (***) below.

**Full code:**

```
class PriceScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PriceScreenState createState() => PriceScreenState();
}

class PriceScreenState extends State < PriceScreen > {
  String selectedCurrency = 'USD';
  String selectedGraphType = "1M";
  Map < String,String > coinValues = {};
  Map < String,double > graphValues = {};
 ***Future futureData;

  bool isWaiting = false;

  getData() async {
    isWaiting = true;
    try {
      Map coinData = await CoinData().getCoinData(selectedCurrency);
      Map graphData = await GraphData().getGraphData( 
        selectedCurrency: selectedCurrency,
        selectedGraphType: selectedGraphType);
      isWaiting = false;
      setState(() {
        coinValues = coinData;
        graphValues = graphData; 
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
 ***futureData = getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Crypto Watcher'),
      ),
      body: ModalProgressHUD(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
       ***child: FutureBuilder(
                future: futureData,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (graphValues.isEmpty) {
                    return new Container();
                  } else
                    print(graphValues);
                  return Graph(closingTimesAndPrices: graphValues);
                }), 
          ),
        inAsyncCall: isWaiting,
        progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best practise is not to defer executing the build method. What you should do is to show a progress bar while the graphValues are being fetched.

Now, you can achieve this in multiple ways. Using bloc, streambuilder etc are some best ways. But for the simplest solution you can use the below code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      if(grapheValues.isEmpty) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      } else {
          Graph(closingTimesAndPrices: graphValues), <<<-------------------
      }
}
```

Hopefully it will help. Let me know if you need any further help. Happy coding!

**UPDATE**
Set isWaiting to true inside the initState method. And then inside the setState of getData() method set isWaiting to true. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I usually pair the next await method in a then(). Something like this:

```
Map coinData = await CoinData().getCoinData(selectedCurrency);
await GraphData().getGraphData(
  selectedCurrency: selectedCurrency,
  selectedGraphType: selectedGraphType).then((graphData ) {
  setState(() {
    coinValues = coinData;
    graphValues = graphData;
  });
});
```