# Instance of model in place of data & Model has no getter length Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an application in Flutter. I am facing an issue with my **Future**. Data from future in future builder giving error Model has no getter length also it is showing in print as `Instance of TopicsModel` inspite of data.

Please help.

Below is my code:

topics_model.dart

```
  class TopicsModel {
  List<Topics> topics = [];

  TopicsModel();

  TopicsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    try {
      topics = jsonMap['topics'] != null
          ? parseTopicsAttributes(jsonMap['topics'])
          : [];

      print(jsonMap['topics']);
    } catch (e) {
      topics = [];
    }
  }

  static List<Topics> parseTopicsAttributes(attributesJson) {
    List list = attributesJson;
    print("in list making");
    List<Topics> attrList = list.map((data) => Topics.fromJson(data)).toList();
    return attrList;
  }
}

class Topics {
  int id;
  String name;

  Topics.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    print("hash problem");
    print(json);
    id = json["sound_id"];
    name = json["title"];
  }
}
```

Future

```
Future<TopicsModel>  getFavTopics() async {
  print("get_only_fav_topics");
  print(userRepo.currentUser.value.userId.toString());
  print(userRepo.currentUser.value.token);
  Uri uri = Helper.getUri('get_only_fav_topics');
  uri = uri.replace(queryParameters: {
    'user_id': userRepo.currentUser.value.userId == null
        ? "0"
        : userRepo.currentUser.value.userId.toString(),
    "app_token": userRepo.currentUser.value.token
  });
  try {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'USER': '${GlobalConfiguration().get('api_user')}',
      'KEY': '${GlobalConfiguration().get('api_key')}',
    };
    var response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (jsonData['status'] == 'success') {
        print("topicssssssssssssssss");
        print(jsonData);
        return (json).decode(response.body)['data'];
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
  }
}
```

FutureBuilder in view

```
child: FutureBuilder<TopicsModel>(
                                  builder: (context, projectSnap) {
                                    print("Projeccct");
                                    print(projectSnap);
                                    if (projectSnap.connectionState ==
                                            ConnectionState.none &&
                                        projectSnap.hasData == null) {
                                      //print('project snapshot data is: ${projectSnap.data}');
                                      return Container();
                                    }
                                    if (projectSnap.connectionState ==
                                            ConnectionState.done &&
                                        projectSnap.hasData) {
                                      print("ind one");
                                      print(projectSnap.data.toString());
                                      return ListView.builder(
                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        itemCount: projectSnap.data.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          return new ChoiceChip(
                                              pressElevation: 0.0,
                                              selectedColor: settingRepo
                                                  .setting
                                                  .value
                                                  .buttonColor,
                                              selected: false,
                                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                              label: Text(projectSnap
                                                  .data[index].name));
                                        },
                                      );
                                    } else {
                                      return Container();
                                    }
                                  },
                                  future: getFavTopics(),
                                )
```

Json response:

```
    {
   "status":"success",
   "data":{
      "topics":[
         {
            "fav_id":1,
            "sound_id":3321,
            "user_id":0,
            "created_at":"2021-05-07 10":"01":25,
            "title":"title 1",
            "sound_name":1620381685.mp3,
            "cat_id":4,
            "parent_id":0,
            "duration":30,
            "album":"Album 1",
            "artist":,
            "tags":null,
            "used_times":0,
            "deleted":0,
            "active":1,
            "image":fLNu9mZDAAHNYJcdNK6YRJPvPVxmpzPidHZRhhW5.jpg
         },
         {
            "fav_id":41,
            "sound_id":3319,
            "user_id":0,
            "created_at":"2021-05-07 09":"58":52,
            "title":"Title 2",
            "sound_name":1620381532.mp3,
            "cat_id":2,
            "parent_id":0,
            "duration":15,
            "album":"Album 1",
            "artist":,
            "tags":null,
            "used_times":0,
            "deleted":0,
            "active":1,
            "image":54PKLMXikjx0KDCHQSL8uep42oXxzF4qtvI7VpHE.jpg
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Now I am returning TopicsModel from my Future. But its giving Instance of 'TopicsModel'
The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'TopicsModel'.

Comment: Can you include the `json` response, it will help to test while solving your question.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh added json response.

Comment: Same error showing tried several methods.

Comment: There are some errors on `json fromat`, like on `sound_name`, `artist`,  `sound_name`, `image`.....

Comment: Can it be the reason for that problem?

Comment: Could be because , length comes after parser and parser will occur on this response

Comment: But feature builder's purpose is to wait for response? Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right, after that it will provide response, you can include `snapshot.hasError` state to see if there are something wrong on `Future`

Answer (score 0):

You need generic 
Change this
`child: FutureBuilder(`
to
`child: FutureBuilder<List<Topics>>(`

Comment: Got type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Topics>>' after change

Comment: And projectSnap.data is null

Answer (score 0):

You didn't connect the Model class with your FutureBuilder. The data will come from model so call the model class like :

```
FutureBuilder<Topics>()
```

Comment: Got type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Topics>>' after change

Answer (score 0):

You call your future with Asynchronously

```
FutureBuilder<List<Topics>>(
       future: getFavTopics(),
       builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Topics>> projectSnap) {
```

For more you can read this article [When should I use a FutureBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983011/when-should-i-use-a-futurebuilder)

Comment: Please check my updated code, Now I am returning TopicsModel.

Comment: just replace `List<Topics>` to `TopicsModel ` in both `FutureBuilder` and `builder` section

Comment: And what are the results of this two lines `print("topicssssssssssssssss");
        print(jsonData);`

Comment: jsonData added to question.

Comment: Can you please help with it?