# how can i display object data in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

Thanks for open my question, i'll post my code first, then i'll put the question below it.

ResultData class

```
ResultData resultDataFromMap(String str) =>
    ResultData.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String resultDataToMap(ResultData data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class ResultData {
  ResultData({
    required this.trxid,
    required this.datetime,
    required this.reqid,
    required this.id,
    required this.responsecode,
    required this.message,
    required this.serverkey,
    required this.result,
  });

  String trxid;
  String datetime;
  String reqid;
  String id;
  String responsecode;
  String message;
  int serverkey;
  List<Result> result;

  factory ResultData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResultData(
        trxid: json["trxid"],
        datetime: json["datetime"],
        reqid: json["reqid"],
        id: json["id"],
        responsecode: json["responsecode"],
        message: json["message"],
        serverkey: json["serverkey"],
        result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromMap(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "trxid": trxid,
        "datetime": datetime,
        "reqid": reqid,
        "id": id,
        "responsecode": responsecode,
        "message": message,
        "serverkey": serverkey,
        "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toMap())),
      };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    required this.stockid,
    required this.itemname,
    required this.unit,
    required this.costperunit,
  });

  String stockid;
  String itemname;
  String unit;
  String costperunit;

  factory Result.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        stockid: json["stockid"],
        itemname: json["itemname"],
        unit: json["unit"],
        costperunit: json["costperunit"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "stockid": stockid,
        "itemname": itemname,
        "unit": unit,
        "costperunit": costperunit,
      };
}
```

searchRequest

```
static searchRequest(String searchVal, hasilSearch) async {
    var searchValue = searchVal;
    try {
      var sendSearch = await http.post(Uri.https('www.domain.net', '/ptemp/'),
          headers: {'x-v2rp-key': '$conve'},
          body: jsonEncode({
            "trxid": "$trxid",
            "datetime": "$datetime",
            "reqid": "0002",
            "id": "$searchValue"
          }));
  var outputResult = jsonDecode(sendSearch.body)['result'] as List;
      print(outputResult);
      List<Result> resData =
          outputResult.map((json) => Result.fromMap(json)).toList();
      print(resData.first);
 } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Response i get from API :

```
{
    "trxid":"1656385782731",
    "datetime":"20220628100942",
    "reqid":"0002",
    "id":"sepatu",
    "responsecode":"00",
    "message":"Success",
    "serverkey":1656385795752,
    "result":[
        {
           "stockid":"COVERSEPATU001",
            "itemname":"Cover Sepatu Plastik APD",
           "unit":"piece","costperunit":"0"
        },
        {
           "stockid":"DIVINGBREATH001SP001",
           "itemname":"Fin\/ Sepatu Selam Kaki Katak",
          "unit":"piece",
          "costperunit":"0"
        },
        {
            "stockid":"DIVINGBREATH001SP009",
            "itemname":"Sepatu Selam",
            "unit":"piece",
            "costperunit":"0"
        
        },
        {
            "stockid":"RAKSEPATU001",
            "itemname":"Rak Sepatu 4 Tingkat",
            "unit":"piece",
            "costperunit":"166309.52"
        }
    ]
}
```

> The Question is = how can i store the response data into Resultdata and result class?, and how can i display them using futurebuilder listview?

i really stuck here for 5 days, been googling and still can't solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply change to

```
      ResultData outputResult = jsonDecode(sendSearch.body);
      print(outputResult);
      List<Result> resData =outputResult.result;
      print(resData.first);
```

Comment: hello, i got this error "type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'ResultData' "

Comment: You can try this
      ResultData outputResult = ResultData.resultDataFromMap(jsonDecode(sendSearch.body));

Comment: it works, thankyou so much; can i ask how can i call the ResultData class to use it in futurebuilder?

Comment: i mean, to display the data using futurebuilder

Comment: You can simply write under the Future method and return result data

Answer (score 0):

so those data classes use from json to covert to class and from json to convert to json:

```
Welcome welcomeFromJson(String str) => Welcome.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(Welcome data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Welcome {
    Welcome({
        this.trxid,
        this.datetime,
        this.reqid,
        this.id,
        this.responsecode,
        this.message,
        this.serverkey,
        this.result,
    });

    String trxid;
    String datetime;
    String reqid;
    String id;
    String responsecode;
    String message;
    int serverkey;
    List<Result> result;

    factory Welcome.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome(
        trxid: json["trxid"],
        datetime: json["datetime"],
        reqid: json["reqid"],
        id: json["id"],
        responsecode: json["responsecode"],
        message: json["message"],
        serverkey: json["serverkey"],
        result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "trxid": trxid,
        "datetime": datetime,
        "reqid": reqid,
        "id": id,
        "responsecode": responsecode,
        "message": message,
        "serverkey": serverkey,
        "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Result {
    Result({
        this.stockid,
        this.itemname,
        this.unit,
        this.costperunit,
    });

    String stockid;
    String itemname;
    String unit;
    String costperunit;

    factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        stockid: json["stockid"],
        itemname: json["itemname"],
        unit: json["unit"],
        costperunit: json["costperunit"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "stockid": stockid,
        "itemname": itemname,
        "unit": unit,
        "costperunit": costperunit,
    };
}
```

Comment: hello sir, can i ask how can i store data to welcome and result class data?

Comment: hello sir as you can use the two line above
Welcome welcomeFromJson(String str) => Welcome.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String welcomeToJson(Welcome data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

Answer (score 0):

Use [json to dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to create your model

Your model:

```
class Model {
  String? trxid;
  String? datetime;
  String? reqid;
  String? id;
  String? responsecode;
  String? message;
  int? serverkey;
  List<Result>? result;

  Model(
      {this.trxid,
      this.datetime,
      this.reqid,
      this.id,
      this.responsecode,
      this.message,
      this.serverkey,
      this.result});

  Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    trxid = json['trxid'];
    datetime = json['datetime'];
    reqid = json['reqid'];
    id = json['id'];
    responsecode = json['responsecode'];
    message = json['message'];
    serverkey = json['serverkey'];
    if (json['result'] != null) {
      result = <Result>[];
      json['result'].forEach((v) {
        result!.add(new Result.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['trxid'] = this.trxid;
    data['datetime'] = this.datetime;
    data['reqid'] = this.reqid;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['responsecode'] = this.responsecode;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    data['serverkey'] = this.serverkey;
    if (this.result != null) {
      data['result'] = this.result!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Result {
  String? stockid;
  String? itemname;
  String? unit;
  String? costperunit;

  Result({this.stockid, this.itemname, this.unit, this.costperunit});

  Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    stockid = json['stockid'];
    itemname = json['itemname'];
    unit = json['unit'];
    costperunit = json['costperunit'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['stockid'] = this.stockid;
    data['itemname'] = this.itemname;
    data['unit'] = this.unit;
    data['costperunit'] = this.costperunit;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And store your data: `var Model data = Model.fromJson(response data);`

Refer `FutureBuilder` widget [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983011/when-should-i-use-a-futurebuilder)