# Json data is empty or had error parsing flutter/dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm busy coding a page in my flutter app where I would like it to display a list view from a json file but it keeps giving error [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "lib/data/json/foods/foods.json".
The asset does not exist or has empty data.

this is my dart json decoder

```
class Food {
  String name;
  double caloriesPer100g;
  double fatPer100g;
  double ofWhichSaturates;
  double carbohydratesPer100g;
  double ofWhichSugars;
  double proteinPer100g;
  double SodiumPer100g;
  double ServingSizeGrams;

  Food(
    this.name,
    this.caloriesPer100g,
    this.fatPer100g,
    this.ofWhichSaturates,
    this.carbohydratesPer100g,
    this.ofWhichSugars,
    this.proteinPer100g,
    this.SodiumPer100g,
    this.ServingSizeGrams,
  );

  Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        caloriesPer100g = json["caloriesPer100g"] ?? 0,
        fatPer100g = json["fatPer100g"] ?? 0,
        ofWhichSaturates = json["ofWhichSaturates"] ?? 0,
        carbohydratesPer100g = json["carbohydratesPer100g"] ?? 0,
        ofWhichSugars = json["ofWhichSugars"] ?? 0,
        proteinPer100g = json["proteinPer100g"] ?? 0,
        SodiumPer100g = json["SodiumPer100g"] ?? 0,
        ServingSizeGrams = json["ServingSizeGrams"] ?? 0;
}
```

this is the first 3 elements of the json file

```
{
            "name": "Chobani Greek Yogurt",
            "caloriesPer100g": 59,
            "fatPer100g": 0,
            "ofWhichSaturates": 0,
            "carbohydratesPer100g": 4,
            "ofWhichSugars": 4,
            "proteinPer100g": 10,
            "SodiumPer100g": 0.04,
            "ServingSizeGrams": 150 
        },
        {
            "name": "Oikos Triple Zero Greek Yogurt",
            "caloriesPer100g": 83,
            "fatPer100g": 0,
            "ofWhichSaturates": 0,
            "carbohydratesPer100g": 6,
            "ofWhichSugars": 6,
            "proteinPer100g": 15,
            "SodiumPer100g": 0.06,
            "ServingSizeGrams": 150 
        },
        {
            "name": "Fage Total 0% Greek Yogurt",
            "caloriesPer100g": 50,
            "fatPer100g": 0,
            "ofWhichSaturates": 0,
            "carbohydratesPer100g": 4,
            "ofWhichSugars": 4,
            "proteinPer100g": 10,
            "SodiumPer100g": 0.05,
            "ServingSizeGrams": 150 
        },
```

and this is the file where i plan to show the list of json foods

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sg_training/data/json/foods/foods.dart';

class AddFood extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddFoodState createState() => _AddFoodState();
}

class _AddFoodState extends State<AddFood> {
  List<Food> _foods = []; // Move _foods list to _AddFoodState

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call fetchFoods method when the widget is initialized
    fetchFoods().then((foods) {
      setState(() {
        _foods = foods;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<List<Food>> fetchFoods() async {
    // Load JSON data from the assets
    String jsonString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString('lib/data/json/foods/foods.json');

    // Decode JSON
    var foodsJson = json.decode(jsonString);

    // Create a list to store parsed Food objects
    List<Food> foods = [];

    // Iterate over the JSON array and convert each item to Food object
    for (var foodJson in foodsJson) {
      foods.add(Food.fromJson(foodJson));
      print(foods);
    }

    return foods;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fetchFoods().then((value) {
      _foods.addAll(value);
    });
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          leading: BackButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          title: Text("SG training"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              child: Padding(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      _foods[index].name,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      _foods[index].caloriesPer100g.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: _foods.length, // Use _foods.length as itemCount
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ive tried two different ways of decoding the json but neither of them work

it should display a list on the screen but it keeps giving an error

i dont know if its the json file the decoder or where i access the decoder but i would be a great help if anyone know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This is because Flutter cannot detect the file path
You need to specify the path in the pubspac.yaml file

```
assets:
  - data/local/food.json
```

It is also better to put your json in an array because the structure is the same but the count is different

Answer (score -1):

You can use a FutureBuilder widget to handle asynchronous operations like fetching data from a JSON file. Here's how you can refactor your AddFood widget to use FutureBuilder

```
    class AddFood extends StatelessWidget {
    Future<List<Food>> fetchFoods(BuildContext context) async {
        // Load JSON data from the assets
        String jsonString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
            .loadString('lib/data/json/foods/foods.json');

        // Decode JSON
        var foodsJson = json.decode(jsonString);

        // Create a list to store parsed Food objects
        List<Food> foods = [];

        // Iterate over the JSON array and convert each item to Food object
        for (var foodJson in foodsJson) {
          foods.add(Food.fromJson(foodJson));
        }

        return foods;
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              leading: BackButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              title: Text("SG training"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder<List<Food>>(
              future: fetchFoods(context),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                  );
                } else {
                  List<Food> foods = snapshot.data;
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Padding(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                foods[index].name,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                foods[index].caloriesPer100g.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade700),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: foods.length,
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

In this version, the fetchFoods function is moved out of the stateful widget and into the AddFood class. The AddFood widget itself is now a stateless widget. The fetchFoods function now takes a BuildContext as an argument to access the context needed for loading the asset.

The UI is built using a FutureBuilder, which handles the asynchronous fetching of data. It displays a loading spinner while waiting for the data, shows an error message if an error occurs, and displays the list of foods once the data is loaded successfully.

Also If you are Familiar with [JsonSerializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package you can rewrite the class in such a way

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'food.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Food {
  String name;
  double caloriesPer100g;
  double fatPer100g;
  double ofWhichSaturates;
  double carbohydratesPer100g;
  double ofWhichSugars;
  double proteinPer100g;
  double SodiumPer100g;
  double ServingSizeGrams;

  Food(
    this.name,
    this.caloriesPer100g,
    this.fatPer100g,
    this.ofWhichSaturates,
    this.carbohydratesPer100g,
    this.ofWhichSugars,
    this.proteinPer100g,
    this.SodiumPer100g,
    this.ServingSizeGrams,
  );

  factory Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$FoodFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FoodToJson(this);
}
```

Make sure you have json_annotation and build_runner dependencies added to your pubspec.yaml file, and run the build command to generate the serialization/deserialization code:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  json_annotation: // any latest version

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: // any latest version
  json_serializable: // any latest version

flutter:
  assets:
    - data/local/
```

then run:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Comment: Thanks the only thing is when you define foods in the addfood file where it displays the ui  snapshot.data is not found

Comment: sorry it is found but cant be assigned to list

Comment: @Ethan my fault, you should use FutureBuilder<List<Food>>, I will update answer

Comment: @Ethan If you are curious why FutureBuilder you may refer to this 
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983011/when-should-i-use-a-futurebuilder) and [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) as well

Comment: @Ethan, please double-check if you have added this JSON to assets and if the path properly appears in the YAML file. Also, try using your JSON in this way [ ... ... ... ] because you have a list, as mentioned in the answer below mine.

Comment: If you still facing any errors note me please @Ethan