# Length of snapshot for Listview on Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, snapshot

I'm need implement a ListView on Flutter, and i'm passing snapshot.data.length as a parameter for itemCount:

```
return ListView.builder(
itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
return ListTile(
title: Text(                            
snapshot.data[index].data["Identificacao"],...
```

Then i got an error:

```
I/flutter ( 4647): Class 'List<DocumentSnapshot>' has no instance getter 'length'.
I/flutter ( 4647): Receiver: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'
I/flutter ( 4647): Tried calling: length
```

But these sintax are used in many tutorials i have seen. I had tried use:

```
snapshot.data.documents.length;
```

but the result is the same. Please help me!

Comment: Was this copy + pasted or is `lenght` misspelled in your source (twice)?  edit: looking again, looks like a typo based on the stacktrace.

Comment: I actually wrote the wrong question here. But there is not even a suggestion (Ctrl + space bar). Because it is a list, I imagine there must be a way to know the size so that you can walk through it with a loop, etc ...

Comment: Almost a week and no response, wow ... I'm glad I chose a popular language maintained by Google to develop my first app

Comment: Lashing out aside, what is `snapshot`?  What tutorials are you following?

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with StreamBuilder, the way to find the length of the data isn't like that.

```
snapshot.data.length
```

will not work since your asking the length for the Instance of the snapshot, So you will have **No Such method** or **No such class** errors

So what you should do is.

```
snapshot.data.snapshot.value.length
```

Let me show you an example

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
              .reference()
              .child("users")
              .orderByChild('firstName')
              .limitToFirst(20)
              .onValue,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.snapshot.value.lenght,//Here you can see that I will get the count of my data
                  itemBuilder: (context, int) {
                  //perform the task you want to do here
                    return Text("Item count ${int}");
                  });
            } else {
              return Container();
            }
      },
  ),
```

you can also take a look at this answer on what is the difference between stream and futurbuilder https://stackoverflow.com/a/50844913/9949983

Answer (score 3):

solved the problem by replacing

```
StreamBuilder<Object>
```

with

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>
```

by default the StreamBuilder comes in this form StreamBuilder

this will work 100%

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

**`builder: (context, snapshot) {}`**

with :

**`builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {}`**

Notice: use your **type** instead of **`List<dynamic>`**

`Text()` class only accepts string value if your type isn't string use `toString()` method :

`Text(snapshot.data![index].toString())`

overall :

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.samples,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<int>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
              return Text(snapshot.data![index].toString());
            },
          );
        }
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to map and increment to get the length of the snapshot:

```
int snapshotLength = 0;

snapshot.data.documents.map<YourGenericType>((document){
 snapshotLength++;
 print("Snapshot length: $snapshotLength");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using StreamBuilder widget in flutter.

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('followers')
                .document(<DocID>)
                .collection('<COLLECTION>')
                .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                QuerySnapshot values = snapshot.data;
                print(values.length);
       },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

only try:
`snapshot.data.documents.length`
not suggest in vscode ide dart plugin but it will work.

Answer (score -2):

maybe `snapshot.documents.length` ?

Comment: There is no such thing.