# Refresh swipe up to refresh FUTUREBUILDER widget flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have an app that gets some data from firebase and than calls a class to display a widget based on the data from firebase. I tried adding a swipe up refresh but i have no idea where to put it and what to to call on refresh. I was trying it using the RefreshIndicator.

Here i will put my code in which it calls the database(firebase) and than creates an widget for each event in the database.

If you need any more information, please feel free to comment. Thank you so much for the help!

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: databaseReference.once(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
        List lists = [];
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
        lists.clear();
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.data.value;
        values.forEach((key, values) {
            lists.add(values);
        });
        return new ListView.builder(
          primary: false,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:12.0,right:12,bottom: 15,),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: lists.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if(lists[index]["Status"]== "Active"){;
          return Container(
          child:EvendWidget(lists[index]["EventImage"], 
                Text(lists[index]["EventName"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["EventLocation"]+ ", "+lists[index] 
                ["EventCounty"] ).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Date"]+ ", "+lists[index]["Time"]+ 
                " - "+lists[index]["Time"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Duration"]+ " H").data,
                Text(lists[index]["Genre"]).data,
                Text(lists[index]["Price"]).data,false));}else{return 
                SizedBox.shrink(); };
            });
        }
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 300),
          child:CircularProgressIndicator());
    }),
```

If you need any more information, please feel free to comment. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: if you want to "refresh" your data multiple times use `StreamBuilder`, not `FutureBuilder`

Comment: what is the difference between streambuilder and futurebuilder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844519/flutter-streambuilder-vs-futurebuilder

Comment: check this for example: https://dev.to/kazuhideoki/how-to-get-data-from-firestore-and-show-it-on-flutterbuilder-or-streambuilder-e05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RefreshIndicator like this:

```
Future<void> _onRefresh() async {
        databaseReference.once();
        return 'success';
      }

return RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: _onRefresh,
             child: ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                     --your code here--
                 }
```

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Comment: so, i have to add the whole futurebuilder inside?

Comment: yes. just wrap your **ListView.builder** in RefreshIndicator and call the  _onRefresh function.

Comment: i wrapped it inside and noting happens when i swipe up, my code now looks like this: http://dontpad.com/codessss

Comment: yeah, exactly like in the video

Comment: thank you so much, please tell me is you need any more information

Comment: try **shrinkWrap: false,**

Comment: if i add it to flase i get an error in the console (Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.) this is why i added it

Comment: please give your full code, it can be fixed, don't worry

Comment: **primary: true**, and make sure your code structure like that : http://dontpad.com/check

Comment: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height - will be fixed by using widget correctly, let me show your code structure.

Comment: sorry i didnt respond, i had to eat something.. if i put primary on true, it shows the refresh indicator but i cannot scroll

Comment: i think i've answer your question, can you please make my answer as accepted? and for scrolling you can show your code or please replace **child:EvendWidget** with other widget, just for check your refresh is working or not, and you are facing not scrolling issue.

Comment: the thing is that it doesnt update the list

Comment: if you want i can put the code somewhere or we can use teamviewer if you want

Comment: have you check your _onRefresh fucntion? is it returning any value/response?

Comment: i added a print and it returns the print in the console so it works

Comment: check your databaseReference.once() is called or not.

Comment: the  databaseReference.once()  is called in the refresh function

Comment: then you need quest and decide, how can you manage your data and show on your app.

Comment: the thing is that it still doesnt work to scroll when i put primary true