# What are the similarities and differences between Future and Stream in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My understanding is that

- a *Future* is used to represent a potential value, or error, that will
  be available at some time in the future. Receivers of a Future can
  register callbacks that handle the value or error once it is
  available.
- *Streams* are part of Dart, and Flutter “inherits” them. There
  are two types of streams in Flutter: single subscription streams and
  broadcast streams. Single subscription streams are the default. They
  work well when you're only using a particular stream on one screen.

What are the similarities and differences between them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter StreamBuilder vs FutureBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844519/flutter-streambuilder-vs-futurebuilder)

Comment: No, my question is regarding Stream vs Future not, StreamBuilder vs FutureBuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both futures and streams are parts of Dart. The main similarity between them is that they are both used for asynchronous programming. The main difference between them is:

- a future is used for a value which may be not available right now, may become available at some later moment, and then will not change. We want to react when the value becomes available (and e.g. display it)
- a stream is used when some value changes over time and we want to react to the changes (e.g. by displaying the current value)

Answer (score 1):

One of the similarities is that both will return in the future(asynchronous). One difference is that Future only returns once. The stream will return again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Similarities:

1. Both are used for asynchronous events

Difference:

1. Data Delivery: Futures provide a single result or error, while Streams deliver a continuous flow of events.
2. Subscription: Futures are consumed once, while Streams can have multiple subscribers, meaning multiple components can receive updates from the same stream.