# I want to use flutter to display algolia results in a listview, but nothing is displayed

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I'm new to flutter and I'm building a program that puts text in Textfield and searches for it in algolia.

It works fine up to the point where I enter text and algolia processes it, but it doesn't return any results and nothing is displayed on the screen.

Is it because I am using Stream Builder? (Would Futurebuilder be better?)
I'm not sure, so I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:algolia/algolia.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../main.dart';

class Application {
  static final Algolia algolia = Algolia.init(
    applicationId: '78CZVABC2W',
    apiKey: 'c2377e7faad9a408d5867b849f25fae4',
  );
}



class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  StreamController<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>> searchController = StreamController();

  Future searchFireStore(word) async {
    Algolia algolia = Application.algolia;
    AlgoliaQuery query = algolia.instance.index("rigaku_index").query(word);
    AlgoliaQuerySnapshot snap = await query.getObjects();
    List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> hits = snap.hits;
    searchController.add(hits);
    print(hits.length);

  }

  final _algilia = Application.algolia;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    searchController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: SearchItems(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: searchController.stream,
              builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text((snapshot.data[index].data['zyugyoumei']));
                    },
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text("No Data"),
                  );
                }

              },

            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchItems extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchItemsState createState() => _SearchItemsState();
}

class _SearchItemsState extends State<SearchItems> {
  String searchWord = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: '検索',
        ),
        controller: TextEditingController(text: searchWord),
        onChanged: (String text) {
          setState(() {
            searchWord = text;
          });
        },
        onSubmitted: (searchWord) =>_SearchState().searchFireStore(searchWord));  }
}
```

There are no error messages, but the snapshot in the StreamBuilder is null. The [hits] in Future is displayed correctly.

Comment: Hi I have edited my answer with a sample recreation from EDIT : so check if that is helful for you ?

Comment: Hi does my posted answer solves your issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following problems solving those should get you your desired result:

1. If you Observe your `searchController` is not typed properly as
   per your data structure type will emit something like

```
StreamController<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>> searchController = StreamController();
```

In this way we know what we expect to return after each hit.

2. You are not setting `searchWord` properly is should be set with using `setState` like following:

```
onChanged: (String text) {
  setState(() {
    searchWord = text;
  });
},
```

3. You are calling `searchFireStore` incorrectly instead of `_SearchState().searchFireStore(searchWord)` you should create instance variable `_SearchState _searchState;` and calling it like `_searchState.searchFireStore(searchWord);` where _searchState is an instance variable of type _SearchState that we have just created.
4. And this last one is just for safety to dispose of the `searchController` properly as follows:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  searchController.close();
  super.dispose();
}
```

And for your using `StreamBuilder` vs `FutureBuilder` debate it depends on your use case like `StreamBuilder` is more appropriate for cases where you expect the data to be updated frequently, while `FutureBuilder` is more appropriate for cases where the data is fetched once and doesn't change often.

In your case, since you're using a stream to receive search results, so in this case `StreamBuilder` seems correct choice.

For more information go through [StreamBuilder vs FutureBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50844913/20239914) and [Algolia ListView Search](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-searchdelegate-algolia-93076a49874f)

**EDIT** :
I have managed to recreate all the algolia with flutter as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:algolia/algolia.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Algolia Search',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Search(),
    );
  }
}

class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SearchState createState() => _SearchState();
}

class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  StreamController<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>> searchController =
      StreamController();
  List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> _results = [];

  final Algolia algolia = const Algolia.init(
    applicationId: '<app_id>',
    apiKey: '<api_key>',
  );

  Future<List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot>> searchAlgolia(String query) async {
    AlgoliaQuery algoliaQuery = algolia.instance.index('demo').query(query);
    AlgoliaQuerySnapshot snap = await algoliaQuery.getObjects();
    return snap.hits;
  }

  void _performSearch(String query) async {
    List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> results = await searchAlgolia(query);
    setState(() {
      _results = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Algolia Search'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            onChanged: (query) => _performSearch(query),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Search...',
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _results.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                AlgoliaObjectSnapshot result = _results[index];
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(result.data['firstname']),
                  subtitle: Text(result.data['lastname']),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So the only thing need to be edited here is app_id api_key and off course the index name and it's values.

Comment: I modified the code, but it still doesn't load: 。。。。

Comment: Any error occured?

Comment: The snapshot is still null.

I have changed the code in question in case you are interested.

Comment: You Still haven't modified this line `onSubmitted: (searchWord) => _SearchState().searchFireStore(searchWord),` it should be `onSubmitted: (searchWord) =>_searchState.searchFireStore(searchWord);` with creating `_searchState` as an instance variable of type `_SearchState`

Comment: Edited code. However, I get an error in the following section.

Undefined name '_searchState'. (Documentation)

Comment: I have rewritten the code since then, but still cannot do it.

When I put a value in the Streambuilder, it is "Null".

Comment: @gadgelogger Hi I have edited my answer with a sample recreation from EDIT : so check if that is helful for you ?