# filtering Data in Firebase and use them

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
This is my Firebase Database.

I want to get the other user's nationality and check if the current user nationality is the same as theirs, then get their name and ... .

This is my code to fetch the data and the field nationality:

```
Future gettingUserDataExplore(String nationality) async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot =
      await userCollection.where("nationality", isEqualTo: nationality).get();
  return snapshot;
}
```

```
class _ExplorePageState extends State<ExplorePage> {

  Stream <QuerySnapshot>? explore;
  @override
  void initState() {
    gettingExploreUsers();
    super.initState();
  }
  gettingExploreUsers() async{
      await DatabaseService(uid: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .gettingUserDataExplore(widget.nationality).then((snapshot) {
            setState(() {
              explore =snapshot;
            });
          });
  }

exploreList() {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: explore,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ExploreList(
                      fullName: snapshot.data.docs[index]['fullName'],
                      imageUrl: snapshot.data.docs[index]['profilePic'],
                      nationality: snapshot.data.docs[index]['nationality'],
                      destination: snapshot.data.docs[index]['destination'],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            : Container();
      },
    );
  }
```

But i get this error :

> _TypeError (type '_JsonQuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?')

I've tried too many ways, but i couldn't get it in a way that i want.
I think i have problem with understanding the firebase commands.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `StreamBuilder` widget in your `build` method. The `StreamBuilder.stream` property expects a [`Stream` object](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams), but you are setting a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html) on it.

The normal way to solve this is to use a `FutureBuilder` instead of a `StreamBuilder`. Even better, you might not need any async builder, since you already call `setState` yourself. That means that in your `build` method you may simply use:

```
exploreList() {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ExploreList(
          fullName: snapshot.data.docs[index]['fullName'],
          imageUrl: snapshot.data.docs[index]['profilePic'],
          nationality: snapshot.data.docs[index]['nationality'],
          destination: snapshot.data.docs[index]['destination'],
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

To learn more about streams, futures and calling setState yourself, I recommend reading:

- Flutter's documentation on [widgets that handle async data](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/widgets/async)
- Dart's documentation on [Streams and Futures](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)
- [Flutter StreamBuilder vs FutureBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844519/flutter-streambuilder-vs-futurebuilder)
- [When should I use a FutureBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983011/when-should-i-use-a-futurebuilder)